# subset in geom_point SOMETIMES returns full dataset, instead of none

Tags: r, ggplot2

I ask the following in the hope that someone might come up with a generic description about the problem.Basically I have no idea whats wrong with my code.

When I run the code below, plot nr. 8 turns out wrong. Specifically the subset in geom_point does not work the way it should. (update: With plot nr. 8 the whole dataset is plottet, instead of only the subset).

If somebody can tell me what the problem is, I'll update this post.

```
SOdata <-     structure(list(id = 10:55, one = c(7L, 8L, 7L, NA, 7L, 8L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, NA, 10L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 
7L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 
6L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 8L), two = c(7L, NA, 8L, NA, 10L, 
10L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 10L, NA, 10L, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 8L, 9L,
10L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 9L), three = c(7L, 
10L, 7L, NA, 10L, 10L, NA, 10L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10L, NA, NA, 
4L, NA, 7L, 7L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 7L, NA, 10L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 7L, 10L), four = c(7L, 10L, 4L, NA, 10L, 7L, NA, 7L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 10L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 10L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, NA, 10L, 7L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 12L, 
4L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 4L, 7L, 10L), five = c(7L, NA, 6L, 
NA, 8L, 8L, 7L, NA, 9L, NA, NA, NA, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 8L, 
NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 
NA, 10L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 10L), six = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2010-05-25", 
"2010-05-27", "2010-06-07"), class = "factor"), seven = c(0.777777777777778, 
0.833333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.888888888888889, 0.5, 
0.888888888888889, 0.777777777777778, 0.722222222222222, 0.277777777777778, 
0.611111111111111, 0.722222222222222, 1, 0.888888888888889, 0.722222222222222, 
0.555555555555556, NA, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.833333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 
0.722222222222222, 0.833333333333333, 0.888888888888889, 0.666666666666667, 
1, 0.777777777777778, 0.722222222222222, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 
0.722222222222222, 0.388888888888889, 0.722222222222222, 1, 0.611111111111111, 
0.777777777777778, 0.722222222222222, 0.944444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 
0.666666666666667, 0.722222222222222, 0.444444444444444, 0.333333333333333, 
0.777777777777778), eight = c(0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.833333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 1, 1, 0.833333333333333, 
0.166666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 1, 1, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333,     
1, 0.666666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0, 0.833333333333333, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 1, 0.833333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.833333333333333, 0.666666666666667), nine = c(0.307692307692308, 
NA, 0.461538461538462, 0.538461538461538, 1, 0.769230769230769, 
0.538461538461538, 0.692307692307692, 0, 0.153846153846154, 0.769230769230769, 
NA, 0.461538461538462, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.615384615384615, 
0.615384615384615, 0.769230769230769, 0.384615384615385, 0.846153846153846, 
0.923076923076923, 0.615384615384615, 0.692307692307692,     0.0769230769230769, 
0.846153846153846, 0.384615384615385, 0.384615384615385, 0.461538461538462, 
0.384615384615385, 0.461538461538462, NA, 0.923076923076923, 
0.692307692307692, 0.615384615384615, 0.615384615384615, 0.769230769230769, 
0.0769230769230769, 0.230769230769231, 0.692307692307692, 0.769230769230769, 
0.230769230769231, 0.769230769230769, 0.615384615384615), ten = c(0.875, 
0.625, 0.375, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.625, 0.875, 1, 0.125, 1, NA, 
0.625, 0.75, 0.75, 0.375, NA, 0.625, 0.5, 0.75, 0.875, 0.625, 
0.875, 0.75, 0.625, 0.875, 0.5, 0.75, 0, 0.5, 0.875, 1, 0.75, 
0.125, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.625, 0.375, 0.625, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 
0.375, 0, 0.875), elleven = c(1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0, 1, 0.9, 0.5, 
0, 0.8, 0.8, NA, 0.8, NA, NA, 0.8, NA, 0.4, 0.8, 0.5, 1, 0.4, 
0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.5, 0.3, 0.9, 0.2, 1, 0.8, 0.1, 1, 0.8, 
0.5, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8, 1, 0.9, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 1), twelve = c(0.666666666666667, 
NA, 0.133333333333333, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.4, 0.733333333333333, NA, 
0.933333333333333, NA, NA, 0.6, 0.533333333333333, NA, 0.533333333333333, 
NA, 0, 0.6, 0.533333333333333, 0.733333333333333, 0.6, 0.733333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.733333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 
0.733333333333333, 1, 0.733333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 
NA, 0.533333333333333, 0.6, 0.866666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 
0.533333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.6, 0.6, 0.866666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.6, 0.6, 0.533333333333333)), .Names = c("id", 
"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", 
"nine", "ten", "elleven", "twelve"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L))


iqr <- function(x, ...) {
  qs <- quantile(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), na.rm = T)
  names(qs) <- c("ymin", "y", "ymax")
  qs
}

magic <- function(y, ...) { 
high <- median(SOdata[[y]], na.rm=T)+1.5*sd(SOdata[[y]],na.rm=T)
low <-  median(SOdata[[y]], na.rm=T)-1.5*sd(SOdata[[y]],na.rm=T)
ggplot(SOdata, aes_string(x="six", y=y))+
stat_summary(fun.data="iqr", geom="crossbar", fill="grey", alpha=0.3)+
geom_point(data = SOdata[SOdata[[y]] > high,], position=position_jitter(w=0.1, h=0),col="green", alpha=0.5)+
geom_point(data = SOdata[SOdata[[y]] < low,], position=position_jitter(w=0.1, h=0),col="red", alpha=0.5)+
stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="point",shape=18 ,size=4, col="orange")
}

for (i in names(SOdata)[-c(1,7)]) {
p<- magic(i)
ggsave(paste("magig_plot_",i,".png",sep=""), plot=p, height=3.5, width=5.5)
}
```

Comment: Should that be SOdata[[y]][SOdata[[y]] > high,] ?

Comment: "...turns out wrong." and "...does not work the way it should." are not very descriptive.  We don't know what your code is supposed to do.  Please tell us what they expected behavior is and how it is different from the observed behavior.

Comment: Yes - you are right Bill the Lizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/labels/data#issue/31

Comment: Thanks Hadley - But that bug is not consitent it seams? cf. my comment to Aniko.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when `y="eight"`, then there are no `y` values above `high`, so `SOdata[SOdata[[y]] > high,]` is an empty data set. Apparently giving `geom_point` an empty data set will make it use the original data set instead, so all points are plotted. A possible solution would be to check for this condition (and same with no points below 'low'), and only add the points when there are points to add.

Comment: Pertaining to hadlyes answers- you are proberly right, Aniko. It was my first guess also. But if it is a bug - it is not consistent. Eg. 
high <- list()
for (i in names(SOdata)[-c(1,7)]) {
high[[i]] =  median(SOdata[[i]], na.rm=T)+1.5*sd(SOdata[[i]],na.rm=T)
}

shows several variables, which has "high" values above 1 (which is the max. possible value)

So it is not just ANY empty data set that causes problems.